# Maximum of a group of overlapping circles

Tags: graphics, regions

I am studying Huygen's principle, and I would like a way to only highlight the wavefront of an advancing wave. At the moment, I have a group of overlapping circles, but I don't know how to highlight only the top part. I thought perhaps FindMaximum would be useful, but I can't seem to make it work. The image below shows the part that I am trying to highlight.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

For some connected disks with random center and radius.

```
regs = Table[
   Disk[{x, RandomReal[{.5, 1}]}, RandomReal[{.5, 1}]], {x, 0, 10, 1}];
circles = RegionBoundary /@ regs;
centers = RegionCentroid /@ regs;
regbd = regs // RegionUnion // RegionBoundary;
contrain = 
  Polygon[Join[{centers[[1]] + {-10, 10}}, 
    centers, {centers[[-1]] + {10, 10}}]];
front = Region[
  RegionIntersection[
   DiscretizeRegion[regbd, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001], contrain], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]
Show[Graphics[circles], front]
```

[image]

**Original**

One way is use `RegionBoundary`.

```
circles = Graphics[Table[Circle[{x, 0}, 1], {x, 0, 10, 1}, {t, 1, 1}]];
disks = Graphics[Table[Disk[{x, 0}, 1], {x, 0, 10, 1}, {t, 1, 1}]];
Show[circles, 
 Region[RegionIntersection[
   RegionBoundary[DiscretizeGraphics[disks, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]],
    HalfSpace[-{0, 1}, 0]], PlotRange -> {-1, 11}, BaseStyle -> Red], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
circles = Table[Circle[{x, 0}, 1], {x, 0, 10, 1}]
```

To find intersections, disks would be more useful. Adjust `MaxCellMeasure` as needed.

```
disks = Table[Disk[{x, 0}, 1], {x, 0, 10, 1}]

r1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion@disks, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
```

[image]

Remove lines from bottom region:

```
top = MeshPrimitives[r1, 1] /. 
   Line[{{_, y1_}, {_, y2_}}] /; y1 < 0 || y2 < 0 -> Nothing;

Show[Graphics@circles, Graphics[{Thick, Red, top}]
 ]
```

[image]